# Import tab delimited text to update MySQL table on remote machine

Tags: php, mysql, file-io, load

The problem lies in UPDATE line. The error I get says
Error: Not unique table/alias: 'tmpStock'
I've never used INNER JOIN before.

```
$link = mysql_connect('host', 'log', 'pwd');
If (!$link) { die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
@mysql_select_db('admin_sandbox') or die ('Unable to select database');

$result = mysql_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpStock
(pid int(10), cid int(10), manufacturer_id int(10), is_visible enum('Yes', 
'No'), product_type varchar(50), is_dollar_days enum('Yes', 
'No'), product_id varchar(64), is_doba enum('Yes', 'No'),is_locked 
enum('Yes', 'No'), 
inventory_control enum('Yes', 'AttrRuleExc') ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT 
CHARSET=latin1 ");

$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sampleproducts.txt' INTO 
TABLE tmpStock FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED 
BY '\n'")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE tmpStock INNER JOIN products ON 
tmpStock.product_id = products.product_id SET 
products.stock = tmpStock.stock WHERE tmpStock.product_id = 
products.product_id") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

Answer (score 0):

You list two tables in `UPDATE` query and then inner join on `tmpStock`, so duplicating the `tmpStock` in query. You can use self-joins but they need an alias. But here it is entirely redundant.

In MySQL, use `INNER JOIN` like you would in a `SELECT` statement only the `FROM` clause is replaced by `UPDATE` at the beginning and `SET` is placed after table joins with `WHERE` clause at very end:

```
"UPDATE tmpStock 
INNER JOIN products ON tmpStock.product_id = products.product_id 
SET products.stock = tmpStock.stock;"
```

Also, I reversed the `SET` expression. Since temp tables are destroyed after user session, you will not see a change in either table. Most likely you want to update the `stock` field in `products` table.

Comment: I had reduced that line, removing most of the 88 field names, to keep this short. I chopped too much. However that got me thinking and I went back through all 88 field names and found some syntax errors. Fixed it, thank you.

Comment: New issue though, the Update query doesn't actually do anything. There's only one line in the sampleproducts.txt file and it isn't being used to update the table. Anything wrong with that that you can see?

Comment: updated the code to what you were saying (I think). No errors, but no update either.

Comment: I think I'm still battling a permissions error? DB is on a different machine.

Comment: Again, which table do you want to update? Temp tables are destroyed after a user session. As you have it `products` table will not be affected. I reversed the `SET` expression to update `products`.